How Can Jenkins check out each commit from Subversion and build individually by Jenkins
I'm new here and have a question about Jenkins with Subversion:
We use SVN as our version control system, and after each commit, Jenkins starts a job. Since we have many developers, it often happens that multiple commits come in while the build process is still running. However, we want each commit to be checked out and built individually by Jenkins.
Does anyone know how we can achieve this most easily?
Thank you in advance!
Unfortunately, the Subversion plugin does not provide an option to check out commits individually.
